# Clojure REST API Frameworks

Tags: rest, clojure

I'm a **Python** developer taking the plunge into **Clojure** and decided that taking on a real project is they best way to get started (after learning syntax of course).  I decided to build a **REST API** for a project that I'm working on.  Things that are worth knowing:

- The database already exists.
- The schema is already defined, implemented, and filled with data.
- The web portion of the app is written in **Django**, which communicates directly with the DB.
- The database is **MySQL**.

So my question is, what is the best framework for creating **REST API** in **Clojure** in late 2014?  I've so far come across **Caribou** and **Liberator**, but don't know how to evaluate which is better (being a **Clojure** noob).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have **several** high-quality options:

- [Liberator](http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/)
- [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) (More like a routing library than a framework)

You can't wrong with any of them. But, from your requirements, [**Liberator**](http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/) seems like a very good choice. Give each of them a try and stick with the one you like the most.

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly the kind of list I'm looking for.  Just checked out Liberator and it seems like the way to go after a deeper dive.

Comment: I'd start out with Compojure + https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc and/or https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql for SQL. Hook some routes up to DB queries. Write some auth* middleware. It's your foundation and often all you need. A tool like Liberator sits on top of Compojure, anyways.

Comment: updated link for Rook: https://github.com/AvisoNovate/rook

Answer (score 3):

I have also written a Webmachine port called [Bishop](https://github.com/cmiles74/bishop). In terms of behavior, it is pretty close to the Erlang and Ruby projects.